# Can anyone help me with my C code please ?

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, scanf

i am trying to make ohm's law program. V= IR.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int V,I,R; 

    printf("please enter the value of the current if the value is not known make I=0 ");
    scanf("%d", &I);
    printf("please entre the value of the resistance if the value is not known make R=0");
    scanf("%d", &R);
    printf("please enter the value of the voltage, if unknown make V=0");
    scanf("%d", &V);

    if (V == 0) 
        V = I*R;
    {
        printf(" V = %d",V);
    }
    else if (I==0)
        I = V/R;
    {
        printf("I = %d ",I);
    }
    else
        R = V/I; 
    {
        printf("R= %d",R);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am beginner, how can i improve my code, so it works ? 
any help is so appreciated thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to help you, we need to know what's your actual problem. What do you expect the program to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: Please read [C tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised.

Comment: You're using integers.  If you divide integer 4 by integer 5 you get zero.

Comment: And properly place your `{}` brackets, around the FULL body of the `if` and `else` clauses.

Comment: And you should have copy/pasted the compiler error messages you're getting into your question.  Several errors are pretty obvious here, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Use floating point variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float V,I,R; 

    printf("welcome to my lovely program");
    printf("please enter the value of the current if the value is not known make I=0 ");
    scanf("%f", &I);
    printf("please entre the value of the resistance if the value is not known make R=0");
    scanf("%f", &R);
    printf("please enter the value of the voltage, if unknown make V=0");
    scanf("%f", &V);
    if (V == 0)
    {
        V = I*R;
        printf(" V = %f",V);
    }
    else if (I==0)
    {
        I = V/R;
        printf("I = %f ",I);
    }
    else
    {
        R = V/I; 
        printf("R= %f",R);
    }
return 0;
}
```

You will get truncated values when dividing if you use `int` and not `float` or `double`. And please learn to indent your code - your if-else blocks are all messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn indentation ,and statements should be given inside the if /else if /else blocks

```
if (V == 0) {
   V = I*R;
   printf(" V = %d",V);
} else if (I == 0) {
   I = V/R;
   printf("I = %d ",I);
} else {
   R = V/I; 
   printf("R= %d",R);
}
```

Make you all the declartions float as you are Dividing in Calculating I and R in 2nd and 3rd because of integer you will only get the integer part.

Answer (score 0):

first - if condition  follows a parenthesis if you have more than 1 lines to execute inside the "if" condition so you should put your first line after the if condition inside the parenthesis ,not only the print statement.same for all the conditional statements you used like elseif

Comment: To most English speakers (with a programming background) "parenthesis" is reserved for the "(" and ")".  The "{}" symbols you're speaking of would be "braces" or "curly brackets" (to distinguish from "[]" "square brackets").  And you should ALWAYS use them to surround `if` and `else` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can write decisions using an if statement without parenthesis, what you did (adding a decision after an if statement, and THEN putting the brackets , THEN adding another decision) is incorrect syntax in C. Generally, I always put decisions in an if or else statement within the brackets as it makes your code easier for you and others to read and edit. So for it to work do the below which is based on the above explanation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int V,I,R; 

    printf("please enter the value of the current if the value is not known make I=0 ");
    scanf("%d", &I);
    printf("please entre the value of the resistance if the value is not known make R=0");
    scanf("%d", &R);
    printf("please enter the value of the voltage, if unknown make V=0");
    scanf("%d", &V);

    if (V == 0) 

    {
     V = I*R;
        printf(" V = %d",V);
    }
    else if (I==0)
        I = V/R;
    {
        printf("I = %d ",I);
    }
    else

    {
    R = V/I;
        printf("R= %d",R);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

However this only works for whole numbers, so if I were you I would use floats or double data types (although refrain from using double data types all the time as it uses more memory than a floating point, and plus you wouldn't really need a number to too many decimal places. Also why have you put parameters within the int main function when you don't use them even once?